# ExtJS application build fails: ReferenceError: d3 is not defined

Tags: javascript, d3.js, extjs

This problem is related to ExtJS's recently released D3 integrated package, and not original one.

If I run 'sencha app watch', it works fine, however it fails if it is ran with 'sencha app build'. This is what I'm shown:

```
ReferenceError: d3 is not defined
...pply(d,f)}}return e},getSvg:function(){return this.svg||(this.svg=d3.select(this...
```

which is clearly sencha's own code (seeing as I don't call d3.*something* anywhere in my code).

So my question boils down to: What are key differences between app watch and build? How would I go about debugging it (I can't even open the file that this error points to, as my text editor freezes if I try to)?

This is the code, where d3 is used (and no where else):

```
Ext.define('Dashboards.view.svgmap.SvgMap', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',

    xtype: 'svgmap',
    requires: ['Ext.d3.interaction.PanZoom', 'Ext.d3.*'],
    controller: 'svgmap',


    config: {
        mapWidth: 800,
        mapHeight: 600,
        styling: [],
        colorRegions: [],
    },
    statics: {
        regionList: [],
    },

    layout: {
        type: 'vbox',
        align: 'stretch'
    },

    find: function(name) {
        ...
    },

    xml : function(url, callback) {
        /*d3.xml function equivalent*/
        ...
    },

    initComponent: function() {
        var me = this;

        this.items = [{
            xtype: 'd3-svg',
            reference: 'svgContainer',
            width: this.getMapWidth(),
            height: this.getMapHeight(),

            interactions: {
                type: 'panzoom',
                zoom: {
                    extent: [1, 4],
                    doubleTap: false,
                    mouseWheel: this.getEnableScroll()
                }
            },

            listeners: {
                scenesetup: function(component, scene) {

                    var regions = me.getColorRegions();
                    var width = me.getMapWidth();
                    var height = me.getMapHeight();
                    var styling = me.getStyling();

                    var svg = scene.append("svg")
                        .attr("width", width)
                        .attr("height", height)
                        .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMinYMin meet")
                        .classed("svg-content", true);


                    me.xml(Dashboards.Properties.serviceRootUrl + "/LietuvosZemelapisNoStyle.svg",
                        function(error, documentFragment) {
                            if (error) {
                                console.log(error);
                                return;
                            }
                            var svgNode = documentFragment
                                .getElementsByTagName("svg")[0];
                            svg.node().appendChild(svgNode);
                            for (var i = 0; i < regions.length; i++) {
                                var r = regions[i];
                                var sel = svg.select('#' + me.find(r.code).id);
                                sel.attr('color', r.color)
                                    .attr('fill', r.color)
                                    .attr('fill-opacity', 1);
                            }


                        });
                }
            }
        }];
        this.callParent(arguments);
    }

});
```

Comment: Do you have d3 package correctly set-up in the requires in the package.json of your app?

Comment: Surely you mean app.json? Yes, "d3" is one of requires elements, besides without it it wouldn't work on `sencha app watch`, but it does.

Comment: Yeah app.json, you can try `sencha app build testing` it could help you with debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After running into same issue again, and stumbling onto my own old unanswered question, I suppose I should write down what fixed it this time.

In app.json, "js" array property was missing an entry

```
{
    "path": "${framework.dir}/build/ext-all-rtl-debug.js"
}
```